# Accelerometer on STM32 Systematic Error Static Test 8.4m/s^2 instead 9.8m/s^2

Tags: accelerometer, stm32, measure

i connected a three axis accelerometer to a STM32 with a friends. 
I runned a static test and the acceleration module was 8,4m/s^2, instead of 9,8m/s^2

I would like to understand the root of the problem :)

What factor can affect this result?

Is possible to apply a linear offset to the three axis to obtain the right value in a static mode?

I know that is no possible to apply a linear offset for the module, but can i work on every single axes?

Is a linear trasformation?

ax (the correct value)= ax'(the value collected by the accelerometer in static condition) + c (the offset value)

Thanks!

Comment: A few questions: What accelerometer part are you using? How is the accelerometer interfaced to the STM32 (Analog signals, SPI)? What code are you using to read the value? What is your static test method? Note for any given axis, you should be able to statically test three positions: Up (1g), down (-1g), and horizontal (0g), and many accelerometers need to be calibrated rather than providing an exact value.

Comment: Triple Axis Accelerometer Breakout MMA7361 from SparkFun here the datasheet https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9652

The accelerometer is interfaced to the STM32 by and analog signals.

@mbmcavoy is not calibrated i found this "brutal" method and i will implement it [link]http://www.gcdataconcepts.com/calibration.html